# how can i display the full decimal points for my Decimal(10,4) field

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-views

i have a database field with the type of Decimal(10,4) at my SQL server 2008, but on my asp.met mvc view the values will only be displayed with two decimal numbers ,, so let say the value in the database is `10.1234` the it will be displayed on the view as `10.12` only.
**So how i can define the field format to display all the decimal point as stored in the database**

**UPDATE:-**
First of all the entity framewrok create a model class for the table and set the object proprty as :-

```
public decimal Result { get; set; }
```

and on the view the result is displayed as follow:-

```
<div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => vlr.Result)
    </div>
    </td>
   <td>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => vlr.DateTaken)
    </div>
```

Even if  the `Result` value in the database is something as `12.1234` ; it will be displayed on the view as `12.12` !!!!.
BR

Comment: Can you show your ASP.NET code and the query? What data type did you specify for the variable in your code?

Comment: thanks for the reply see my update to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Add a DataAnnotation to the model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,###,##0.0000}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal Result { get; set; }
```